# Google static maps api - parameter doesn't work hl=ru

Tags: api, static, maps

```
$pic  = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?hl=ru&center=55.6373,34.3276&zoom=6&size=640x135&scale=2");
file_put_contents('/var/www/mysute.ru/img/1.jpg',$pic);
```

I try to save the maps image on the server, but the image remains not in that language which I set in where wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give correct location for file_put_contents in server..

`file_put_contents('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/var/www/mysute.ru/img/1.jpg',$pic);`

check and tell, its really work for me...

Comment: thanks your answer for my questions. But my path is correct and picture saved successful result. If to watch the image according to the link: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?hl=ru&center=55.6373,34.3276&zoom=6&size=640x135&scale=2 - here correct result. If to watch the saved image on the server, it another, the name of the cities and streets on other languages. I won't understand why so occurs. Try if there is an opportunity. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: this is result work script: https://leto9g.storage.yandex.net/rdisk/0f9d0aaf24285cb49e8d3a03ef4070ff/mpfs/OqRAAIp1JrDtTF10zV64QJZmkrttjfy5mD2v_CYUWXnoFJwsGuMnO09TyOhBqmGD1vMq7u-lURqupc8wx8bFIA==?uid=0&filename=1.jpg&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fjpeg&rtoken=cf07767b631e0f5eb7d6248586dfe8e5&rtimestamp=538daefc&force_default=no Image another

Comment: @stopgg Oh.. now i understand. i will try and tell you asap.

Comment: Fine, thanks. Still I will mark, if put a code HTML <img src="url"> - here is ok. The problem takes place only when saving a map in the file.